# Visual States and a custom dependency property (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm stuck trying to add a dependency property to a button. I have several buttons located in my header view and clicking on them changes the content in the ContentControl between different views. All this works great. I want the button that was clicked have a different forecolor than the others and it looks like I need to add a dependency property. I think I have all the pieces in place but can't figure out how to get them all to work together.

I have a string property named ViewState in my viewmodel which changes based upon the button being clicked. The property is changing and I'm calling RaisePropertyChanged when it happens. What do I need to do to bind the additional dependency property? I'm transitioning from the WinForm world and trying to mentally piece it all together but struggling a bit.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="LocalButtonTemplate">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor"  Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="outerBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="4">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ViewState">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Dashboard">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" To="Yellow"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="AccountTables">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" To="Red"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" To="Purple"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" To="#35A84D"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                <Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                      Margin="4,5,4,4"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

My buttons:

```
    <dxwuii:SplitPanel Margin="0,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2" ItemSpacing="0" Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSizeMode="AutoSize" >
        <Button Command="{Binding SendViewModelNameCommand, Mode=OneTime}" CommandParameter="AccountTablesViewModel" Style="{StaticResource LocalButtonTemplate}">Express Tables</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding SendViewModelNameCommand, Mode=OneTime}" CommandParameter="MappingViewModel" Style="{StaticResource LocalButtonTemplate}">Item Mapping</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding SendViewModelNameCommand, Mode=OneTime}" CommandParameter="ReportsViewModel" Style="{StaticResource LocalButtonTemplate}">Reports</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding SendViewModelNameCommand, Mode=OneTime}" CommandParameter="PostBalancesViewModel" Style="{StaticResource LocalButtonTemplate}">Post Balances</Button>
    </dxwuii:SplitPanel>
```

Dependency Property Class:

```
namespace MyAppName.Model
{
    public class StateManager : DependencyObject
    {
        public static string GetVisualStateProperty(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(VisualStatePropertyProperty);
        }
        public static void SetVisualStateProperty(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(VisualStatePropertyProperty, value);
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualStatePropertyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "VisualStateProperty",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(StateManager),
            new PropertyMetadata((dependencyObject, args) =>
            {
                var frameworkElement = dependencyObject as FrameworkElement;
                if (frameworkElement == null)
                    return;
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(frameworkElement, (string)args.NewValue, true);
            }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `Tag` and `Attached` property on your each button as below. `Tag` value will be the `VisualState` value to which button should go on click.

```
  <Button Tag="AcountTables" local:StateManager.VisualStateProperty="{Binding YOURVIEWMODELPROPERTY}" Command="{Binding SendViewModelNameCommand, Mode=OneTime}" CommandParameter="AccountTablesViewModel" Style="{StaticResource LocalButtonTemplate}">Express Tables</Button>
```

Update your `AttachedProperty` like:

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualStatePropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "VisualStateProperty",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(StateManager),
        new PropertyMetadata((dependencyObject, args) =>
        {
            var frameworkElement = dependencyObject as FrameworkElement;
            if (frameworkElement == null)
                return;

            if (args.NewValue == frameworkElement.Tag.ToString())
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(frameworkElement, (string)args.NewValue, true);
            }
            else
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(frameworkElement, "Normal", true);
            }

        }));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's working as expected now but I've run into one more issue. I added a 'MouseOver' state and it changes the color but the color sticks and doesn't return to it's previous state.